# Creating a type trait to detect functors in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, functor, type-traits

Considering the following custom definition:

> A functor is a (possibly final) (possibly union) class with a publicly overloaded `operator()`.

How to define a type trait:

```
template <class T> 
struct is_functor {
    static constexpr bool value = /* something */
};

template <class T>
inline constexpr bool is_functor_v = is_functor<T>::value;
```

that evalues to `true` when `T` is such a functor, and `false` otherwise, in standard `C++17`?

Comment: You need to know the parameters to the `()` operator, then use the ol' reliable `decltype`+`std::declval` combo, stick it inside `std::void_t`, and SFINAE on that. You might be able to get away without knowing the parameters to the `()` operator if it's not overloaded, and there's only one `()` operator in the class; by trying to take the address of it.

Comment: not sure if this covers all cases, but consider `std::is_invocable<>` and `std::is_class<>`

Comment: Why would you need to ask this question? What kind of code are you going to write where you can take a type that has an `operator()` *without* having some signature in mind for that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt (non-working counter examples are welcome)

```
struct _argument {
    template <class T> constexpr operator T&() const& noexcept;
    template <class T> constexpr operator T&&() const&& noexcept;
};

template <class F, class Args = std::tuple<>, std::size_t N = 128, class = void>
struct _min_arity {};

template <class F, template <class...> class T, class... Args, std::size_t N>
struct _min_arity<F, T<Args...>, N, std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Args) <= N>>
: std::conditional_t<
    std::is_invocable_v<F, Args...>,
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>,
    _min_arity<F, std::tuple<Args..., _argument>, N>
> {};

template <class F, class = void, class = void>
struct _has_function_call_operator
: std::false_type
{};

template <class F>
struct _has_function_call_operator<
    F,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_class_v<F> || std::is_union_v<F>>,
    std::void_t<decltype(_min_arity<F>::value)>
>
: std::true_type
{};

template <class T>
struct is_functor
: std::bool_constant<_has_function_call_operator<T>::value>
{};
```